# Addthis smart layers not working

Tags: addthis

I'm trying to use the mailing service from addthis. I only want the mail, no other sharing button. Here's my code:

```
<li><a class="addthis_button_compact"><span class="icon-send"></span></a></li>

<script>
    addthis.layers({
        'share' : {
            'services' : [
                {'service' : 'email', 'ra-5509841b45b7ba5b' : 'AddThis'}
            ]
        },
        'follow' : {}
    });
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5509841b45b7ba5b"></script>
```

The problem is I always see a dropdown with a lot of different services (facebook, gplus, twitter, ecc). What am I doing wrong?
I just want the user to be able to click on an Icon I define (a briefcase) and be prompted with the mail form.

Comment: Did you check your settings on the addthis account?  I think you might need to control it there.

Comment: I did but if I set it up on my account and then use 'addthis_sharing_toolbox' instead of button_compact it works but it won't let me cusomize the icon

Comment: Hmm... sorry.  That's the only way I know to change which buttons appear.

Answer (score 0):

The format for adding an inline button is addthis_button_[service_name]. 
Here's a list of the available services that AddThis provides:
https://www.addthis.com/services

If you wanted the AddThis email button, you would use this class name:

```html
<a class="addthis_button_email">
```

Rather than:

```html
<a class="addthis_button_compact">
```